# Shoes.exe is not responding

Tags: ruby, shoes

I want to run next simple example:

```
Shoes.app(title: 'Log In', width: 300, height: 300) do
      flow do
        caption 'Login'
        @login = edit_line :width => '100%', :text=>""
      end
end
```

After I switched to another window and wait ~10sec, shoes.exe is not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already registered on github:
https://github.com/shoes/shoes/issues/266